# catch errors for firebase login and display to the user with two-way binging not working

Tags: firebase-authentication, ionic3, angular6

I have a very simple straight-forward login template, and I'm using the Firebase to centralize login options.

**[part1]** Problem is, for some reason, most of the browser except Chrome - receiving a error:

```
This browser is not supported or 3rd party cookies and data may be disabled
```

Do I have any firebase configuration issues or something ? because I don't see any posts about these issues - and I can't be the only one experiencing this... ( only Chrome works w/o issues )

I can't start telling people to configure their browser?! ...

**[part 2]** at least, I'm trying to catch those errors - and display them to the user, otherwise, he has no idea what's the problem and it seems that the app isn't doing anything ( popup opens then close and that's it )

**login.ts**

```
verifyErrorMsg() {
    console.log("this.loginError:", this.loginError);
}

loginWithGoogle() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider())
        .then(userData => {
            console.log("success - moving to main page");

        }).catch(error => {
            this.loginError = error;
            this.verifyErrorMsg();  // show the real error, but in console
        });
}
```

^^^ there's no `this` issue here .. verified that this is the real object.

**template.html**

```
<button ion-button (click)="verifyErrorMsg()">
   Check login error value
</button>

<p color="danger">
   {{ loginError.message }}
</p>
```

The funny/strange part here is, when I click on my test button to verify what's the real value of this very moment - then suddenly the `<p>` gets update, even though the function `verifyErrorMsg` only prints to console ...

I guess it's a `cycle` or `digest` kind of thing .. but I'm not sure what needs to be done here ... ?

Comment: this isn't actually call'ed two-way data binding ( only when using `ngModel` ) this is actually called `interpolation` and they are not two-way. in order to detect changes to those variables - we need to use `ChangeDetectorRef`: review answer in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39673030/angular-2-function-inside-callback-value-not-updating-view

Comment: but if someone can help me with part #1 - that would be great